# Sendkeys to send % sign to textbox

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to send a `'%'` sign to my textbox through the `SendKeys.Send()` method.

I already know that you should enclose the `'%'` by braces.

This command should be correct :

```
 SendKeys.Send("{%}");
```

But I get a `'5'` instead of a `'%'` in my textbox.

I tried this on VS.Net 2010/2012 and 2015, all with the same result.

PS : My regional settings/keyboard are 'NL-be' in case this matters.

Comment: Why are you sending keys to your own text box rather than just setting its text directly?

Comment: It's a touch enabled application ( POS Cash Register ) and we use a virtual keyboard that we developed ourselfses.

Comment: I am having the same problem here. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

According to MSDN:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx

The character represents a key code on the keyboard, you should combine it with SHIFT.

So try SendKeys.Send("+5");

"+" Represents the SHIFT key.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/59251988/4634377

You must call Send with '+' which is code for SHIFT and then 'ù':

```
SendKeys.Send("+ù");
```