# SendKeys.SendWait("{%}") writes "5" instead of "%"

Tags: c#, winforms, sendkeys

I am writing an app which uses `SendKeys` to send text at the cursor whenever text is available. Each time the app has to write the percentage sign, it writes number 5 instead. I send `10{%}` and my output is `105`. I can't figure how to simply make the `%` symbol appear.

From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys?view=netframework-4.7.1#Remarks) :

> The plus sign (+), caret (^), percent sign (%), tilde (~), and
>   parentheses () have special meanings to SendKeys. To specify one of
>   these characters, enclose it within braces ({}). For example, to
>   specify the plus sign, use "{+}". To specify brace characters, use
>   "{{}" and "{}}".

Here is a really simple sample to reproduce the issue (ConsoleApp with System.Windows.Forms reference)

```
namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

            string text = "10{%}";

            // Output SHOULD be "10%"
            // Output IS "105"
            System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait(text);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Output is `105` instead of `10%`.

I can't figure this out, how can I write `%` symbol using SendKeys ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18299388/1390548 - Duplicate

Comment: @Jawad i'll try to be more clear in my question for it's not the same issue : i just can't write '%' with sendkeys

Comment: @Raphaël do you need to display the braces as well?

Comment: @dunnel123 no, I just want to display the `%` symbol

Comment: Try: `SendKeys.SendWait("\{%\}");`

Comment: `string text = "10+{%}";`

Comment: @VillageTech : `"\{"` is an unrecognized escape sequence, and adding `@` before throws a System.ArgumentException : `Keyword "%\" is not valid.'`
@Jimi : the output is still `105`

Comment: @Raphaël: Try "10'" (one, zero, apostrophe)...

Comment: @LaurentLARIZZA output is `10'`

Comment: And what about "10+ù" ?

Comment: this works, thanks! is this for it doesn't work with `{%}` on AZERTY keyboards ?

Comment: On QWERTY keyboards, % is Shift+5. I just made you send the Shift+ù key instead. (I just figured, since you have the trema in your name, that you were using an AZERTY keyboard... de rien ;) )

Comment: yeah, got it with the key combination used. but that should not be this way no ? merci beaucoup en tout cas :D

Comment: Remember, with `SendKeys`, you're sending keys, not characters. I wonder why `{%}` does not correctly locate the `ù` key though.

Comment: especially as keys such as `(`, `)`, `{` or `~` which has different keys combination in fr-fr and en-us works perfectly fine

Comment: @Raphael: I finally explained it ans updated my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string text = "10+ù";
```

Your culture is `fr-fr`, you're using an AZERTY keyboard. `%` is located in shift position with regards to `ù`, so it should do the trick.

UPDATE: I finally took the time to look it up : https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/SendKeys.cs,a40b41f572ed230f

Have a look at the `keywords` array. Indeed, `{%}` and `{^}` are treated specially and really mean `Shift+5` and `Shift+6` regardless of keyboard layout. This explains why you're getting `105` when feeding `10{%}` to the function with an AZERTY layout.

Comment: Thanks for the further explanation !

Answer (score 1):

Use the @ operator before the string value for a string literal.

E.g. `string text = @"10{%}";`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim

Comment: The output for `System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait(@"10{%}");` is still `105` in my application. Does this work on your environment ?

Comment: Yeah I see `10%` in my environment. VS 2019 .NET 4.7.2 using a new console app project

Comment: I just tried with the exact same configuration without success, I must be missing something somewhere else

Comment: @Raphael, what locale are you using? `en-us` (english) ? What are keyboard settings in the OS? It seems that it is detected by OS like `[SHIFT}+'%'`, so maybe your PC is something egzotic?

Comment: Can you run `Get-Culture` in Powershell and tell me the culture you're using?

Comment: @VillageTech : Please. AZERTY is not THAT exotic :)

Comment: @VillageTech nope, i'm using `fr-fr` with an azerty keyboard

@dunnel123 : 1036 | fr-FR

Comment: Ok, so there's a bug on sendkeys with azerty keayboards :/ thank you very much for your time!

Comment: @Raphaël see Laurents answer, he's cracked it :)

Answer (score 0):

That is weird Raphaël. I copy-pasted your code in a Sample C# project and I get `10%` as the output. Are you using any of the mentioned supported platforms, from the link you have provided -

> Applies to
>
> .NET Core
>
> 3.0
>
> .NET Framework
>
> 4.8 4.7.2 4.7.1 4.7 4.6.2 4.6.1 4.6 4.5.2 4.5.1 4.5 4.0 3.5 3.0 2.0 1.1

Comment: Laurent solved this : as I'm using an AZERTY keyboard, `{%}` is understood as QWERTY and the key combination results in `5` instead of `%`, which is weird indeed. Thank you for testing!

Comment: nice. Happy to help

Comment: @Raphaël: Well, it's weird that it still correctly locates the `'`key, but not the `{%}`. I suppose, because `%` has meaning for `SendKeys`, that MS just hard-coded the `{%}` behaviour as `Shift+5`, disregarding exotic keyboard layouts such as AZERTY.

Comment: "Please. AZERTY is not THAT exotic :)". :). It's really likely as `^` behave the same and gives `6`